# C# Shell Thumbnail doesnt work properly on ppt files

Tags: c#, shell, thumbnails

I have the following function to get `BitmapImage` of file.

```
public static BitmapImage GetThumbnail(string filePath)
{
    ShellFile shellFile = ShellFile.FromFilePath(filePath);
    BitmapSource shellThumb = shellFile.Thumbnail.ExtraLargeBitmapSource;

    BitmapImage bImg = new BitmapImage();
    PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(shellThumb));
    encoder.Save(memoryStream);
    bImg.BeginInit();
    bImg.StreamSource = memoryStream;
    bImg.EndInit();

    return bImg;
}
```

When I get Video's Thumbnail it always works.
When I get Presentation (pptx) Thumbnail it doesn't work properly (I have no idea when it does and when it doesn't).

For example, I have 2 files in directory:
[image]

And this is how it looks in my program - 1 is ok and 1 isn't (sometimes both are ok, and sometimes both aren't):
[image]

I would appreciate if you could tell me what's the problem or maybe give me another way of getting the Thumbnail that will not fail...

**p.s.**
I would like to remind that with video files it works 100% fine (.mp3, .mp4, .wmv - thats what I tested)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I wanted to get pptx thumbnail, I came up with the following solution:
1. I extracted the thumbnail using DotNetZip
2. I got the thumbnail which is located in docProps directory
3. I extracted the thumbnail to `memoryStream`
4. I converted the `memoryStream` to `BitmapImage` and returned it.

here's the code:

```
public static BitmapImage GetPPTXThumbnail(string filePath)
{
    using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(filePath))
    {
        ZipEntry e = zip["docProps/thumbnail.jpeg"];

        BitmapImage bImg = new BitmapImage();
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        bImg.BeginInit();
        e.Extract(memoryStream);
        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        bImg.StreamSource = memoryStream;
        bImg.EndInit();

        return bImg;
    }
}
```

Cant fail with this solution, this solution is only to get PPTX Thumbnail, I assume it works with all office xml files such as docx, xlsx, etc...